# Jquery Youtube Iframe Mouseenter and Mouseleave on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have much Videos on the website and i wat on a hover that the hovered iframe play. and on mouseleave it should stop playing.

The hover and play works. But the Mouseleave dont work and i dont know why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".youtube").each(function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/hqdefault.jpg)');
      $(document).delegate('#' + this.id, 'mouseenter', function() {
    if($(this).data('mouseenter')) {
     return;
    }
    $(this).data('mouseenter', true);

        var iframe_url = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1";
        if ($(this).data('params')) iframe_url += '&' + $(this).data('params');
        var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'allowfullscreen':'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder': '0', 'src': iframe_url})
        $(this).append(iframe);
      });
     var playersrc=$('.youtube').attr('src');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Need HTML since this involves mouse events. A working example would be nice, since you got the mouseenter part working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate('#' + this.id, 'mouseleave', function() {
            if($(this).data('mouseleave')) {
                alert("not first time, but mouseleave is still detected");
                return;
            }
            alert("first time your cursor is quitting this iframe, mouseleave detected");
            $(this).data('mouseleave', true);
        });
```

This works for me!